# SSIS 2005 Saving Problem - SQL Task Editor

Tags: ssis

I have a relatively big SSIS package which I'm trying to edit. I basically need to update a query on an Execute SQL Task. Problem is the solution is not saving the query when I do the change. I open the SQL Task, change the query and close the task. I verify the change before saving and it's there but as soon as I click on the save button the change on the query disappears.

I verified for opened instances of the package but there are no other sessions on the machine. It does seems to be saving correctly on other packages included in the solution, but for some reason is not saving on my main package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have a backup copy of your package before you try this:

- close the package (but keep the solution open)
- right click the package and view code
- search for your query and replace the query text with your new query text
- save it
- now double click the package to open it up like you normally do and view the query

Comment: This worked. Is there a particular reason as to why the design mode is not allowing this update?

Comment: I truly have no idea why design mode does not allow this. An SSIS guru I know saved my life with by telling me how to go into code and make my changes.